# Is it possible to get source code of my Android device?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I have background about android application development and now I want to explore deeper side of the Android.

Because of Android is open source, I want to find my phone's source code, then change some values in code, and after all I can compile and flash the code into the phone and see the changes.

I know there is an android documentation [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) but it is not clear for me.

So, my question is how can I download the source code of my phone?

Comment: Android itself is open source however the system images of the different devices aren't.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified your device type so here are some more general ideas:

Basically it is not that simple and depends on your device. Parts of Android are open source, other parts are not. Furthermore, your Android device can have a locked bootloader which won't allow you to install your custom build firmware.

Your link shows you how to download the current Android source code using the repo tool. Usually, Android is not in a single git repo. The repo tool reads from a configuration file the different git repositories, current branches, etc. and clones them for you.

I did Android development for OMAP devices (in the past). OMAP itself is outdated but you can learn alot from the documentation: http://omapedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Furthermore, you can still buy OMAP dev boards and play around with them, build a custom image, patch things, etc.

Building a custom Android for OMAP devices works like this:

- Clone Android source code
- Clone Linux Kernel
- Clone U-Boot bootloader
- Build all three and create image files
- Flash them on the device

A few words about open source: Many things ar eopen source, but not everything. E.g. GPU driver are closed source. In case of OMAP devices, you can get them precompiled. So if you want to touch something which is not open source, you run into problems.

I hope that helps you and points you a little bit into the right direction.